# How can i add a template in all the pages except in category page

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-template

I have a template called **test.phtml** in `\magento\app\design\frontend\rwd\newtheme\template\test\test.phtml`

In **page.xml** layout file I am not getting how to add my template to appear in **all pages** except **product page**.

Comment: in which block you want to display the template?

Comment: in content block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add two layout update in your `layout.xml` file

**First to add your template in all pages**

```
<default>
    <reference name="content"> // Changes you reference accordingly
         <block type="core/template" name="customtestblock" template="test/test.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</default>
```

**Second to remove block from category page**

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <remove name="customtestblock"/>
</catalog_category_default>

<catalog_category_layered>
    <remove name="customtestblock"/>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Comment: There is no file called layout.xml in layout folder. Should I create it?

Comment: it was just an example, you can add it to any existing module's layout file or in `local.xml` file